# Proving nonexistence of membership loops using Foundation only

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to work through the following problem:

Problem: assuming no axiom, let there be sets $x, y, z$ such that $x \in y, y\in z, z\in x$. Prove that this violates the axiom of foundation. Foundation is formulated using $\in$-minimals: $\forall x(\exists y \in x \rightarrow \exists z(z\in x \wedge \forall w\ w\in x \rightarrow w\notin z))$

It seems like the usual proof of forbidding infinite descending membership chains fails here because you are not allowed the necessary axioms like Replacement and Pairing. I've tried looking at the $\in$-minimal elements in $x,y,z$, but I haven't been able to go anywhere. So hints and pointers are appreciated!

Comment: How, in FOL language, is no infinite membership descent proven just using foundations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be right. Let $\in = \{(a,b),(b,c),(c,a)\}$ over a universe $\{a,b,c\}$.

Then $\forall w(w\in x\to w\not\in z)$ is equivalent to $x\ne z$ in this model.

So Foundation becomes:
$$\exists y(y\in x)\implies \exists z\ne x(z\in x)$$
But this holds in our model.